# How to save the updated total of stocks after it minus ? [php-json]

Tags: php, jquery, json

How to save the updated total of stocks after it minus ? [php-json]
i need to get the current stocks and minus it to the quantity bought by the customer. and it will post to the order.json and get the total payment and
i need to update the food.json for the stocks and to put the orderlist on order.json 
This is the code to get the value of buy product but the quantity entered by the customer do not minus on the stocks and do not get the total. I think there is wrong in my codes. Please Help me. Im just a beginner to json

```
<?php
        if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
            $id = (int) $_GET["id"];
            $getfile = file_get_contents('food.json');
            $jsonfile = json_decode($getfile, true);
            $jsonfile = $jsonfile["records"];
            $jsonfile = $jsonfile[$id];
        }

        if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
            $id = (int) $_POST["id"];
            $getfile = file_get_contents('food.json');
            $all = json_decode($getfile, true);
            $jsonfile = $all["records"];
            $jsonfile = $jsonfile[$id];

            $quan   = $_POST['quan'];




            $stocks = $stocks - $quan; // on minusing the stocks :<

            $post["pname"] = isset($_POST["pname"]) ? $_POST["pname"] : "";
            $post["price"] = isset($_POST["price"]) ? $_POST["price"] : "";
            $post["stocks"] = isset($_POST["stocks"]) ? $_POST["stocks"] : "";
              // $post["quan"] = isset($_POST["quan"]) ? $_POST["quan"] : "";



            if ($jsonfile) {
                unset($all["records"][$id]);
                $all["records"][$id] = $post;
                $all["records"] = array_values($all["records"]);
                file_put_contents("food.json", json_encode($all));
            }
            header("Location:index_crudjson.php");
        }
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta name="description" content="tutorial-boostrap-merubaha-warna">
            <meta name="author" content="ilmu-detil.blogspot.com">
            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">

            <style type="text/css">
            .navbar-default {
                background-color: #3b5998;
                font-size:18px;
                color:#ffffff;
            }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
              </button>
              <h4>JSON Bake Shop</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- /.navbar -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3>Buy a Product</h3>
                </div>

                <?php if (isset($_GET["id"])): ?>
                <form method="POST" action="buy.php">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>" name="id"/>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputFName">Product Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="inputFName" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["pname"] ?>" name="pname" placeholder="Product Name">
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputLName">Price</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" required="required" id="inputLName" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["price"] ?>" name="price" placeholder="Price">
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputAge">Stocks</label>
                        <input type="number" required="required" class="form-control" id="inputAge" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["stocks"] ?>" 
                         name="stocks" placeholder="Stocks">
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputAge">Quantity</label>
                        <input type="number" required="required" class="form-control" id="inputAge" value="<?php echo $jsonfile["quan"] ?>" 
                         name="quan" placeholder="Quantity">
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Buy</button>
                        <a class="btn btn btn-default" href="index_crudjson.php">Back</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
                <?php endif; ?>


            </div> <!-- /row -->
        </div> <!-- /container -->
        </body>
        </html>
```

This is the attached sample of order.json, food.json, index and buy.php[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDKNc.jpg)[food.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ8Op.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple error on you `$post` assignment

```
$post["stocks"] = $stocks;
```

I could not understand clearly your logic, but `$stocks` is not used at all, and the real stocks value should not be in `$_POST`.

Comment: i need to get the current stocks and minus it to the quantity bought by the customer. and it will post to the order.json and get the total payment

Comment: i need to update the food.json for the stocks and to put the orderlist on order.json

Comment: Please attach examples of your JSON structure

Comment: I attach it on picture above

Comment: Look, setting your `$post["stocks"]` with the value you retrieve from page will make stocks never be updated.